# IntelliJ - Java - Missing src folder after pulling from github

Tags: java, intellij-14

I am working on a project in Inteillij with some classmates and pulled what they worked on in the master branch.  When I launched Intellij I think I remember seeing the java files in there along with our tests but after opening the terminal and switching to my personal branch, they were gone.  I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this.  I've tried pulling again, but it says its up to date.  I closed Intellij and opened it again and have also invalidated caches and restarted but nothing has worked.

[Here is what my screen looks like when I launch Intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exlmm.png)

Comment: This likely has nothing to do with IntelliJ.  If you believe that the missing files are in your Git branch, and you think IntelliJ has deleted them, then doing a `git status` will show you that they have been deleted.  What does `git status` show you?  If it shows that everything is up to date and no local files have been deleted, then the problem is likely that the files you think have gone missing aren't in your Git branch.

Comment: I think I get what you are saying. Could you walk me through how I get what was in the master branch into my personal branch without interfering with my classmates work?
I assume I would `git checkout master`, then `git merge "my_branch"` to see what was in master but I am not sure and don't want to screw over my teammates.  Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: Sorry for my "comment and run" :) - You want to go the other way.  You wan to merge "master" into your branch.  So you want to do 1) `git checkout master` 2) `git pull` 3) `git checkout my_branch` 4) `git merge master`.  - Hopefully you won't have any merge conflicts.  What you'll then have is your branch plus whatever changes have been made to "master" since you branched off of it.

Comment: @CryptoFool Thank you for your help!  I appreciate it :)